# Exchange Server 2010 SP1: Powershell scripting

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

How can I get a list of users that got the checkbox unchecked for advanced security "Allow inheritable permissions..." on the Exchange Server 2010 ?

How can I enable it bulk using AD PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
get-qaduser -sizelimit 0 -securitymask DACL | get-qadpermission
```

You'll need the Quest AD cmdlets to try this. Download from here:

http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx